# JavaFx restored window not getting focus on mac, if another application is selected

Tags: javafx

Am running a JavaFx application on mac OSX 10.10

I am minimizing the window using:

```
primaryStage.setIconified(true);
```

And then restoring the window by using:

```
primaryStage.setIconified(false);
primaryStage.requestFocus();
myTextBoxOnStage.requestFocus();
```

There are two different scenarios:

1. If the JavaFx window is hidden, and I DON'T click on any other
   application, then the JavaFx window is restored using the method
   above, then all is good.  The JavaFx window is displayed and the component myTextBoxOnStage has focus.
2. If the JavaFx window is hidden, then I DO click on
   another application, then the JavaFx window is restored, then although my JavaFx application comes to the front, the previous application that I clicked on remains with the focus.

It is scenario #2 that I am trying to solve.

To check whether the JavaFx window was getting focus, but then losing it somehow, I installed a listener:

```
primaryStage.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, t, t1) -> {
    System.out.println(t1 ? "IN FOCUS!": "NOT IN FOCUS");
});
```

However in scenario #2, the JavaFx window never gets focus.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not on MAC so, it is just a guess, but you could try to install a listener to "primaryStage.iconifiedProperty()", and request the focus in the listener body (in case of the new value is false).

Comment: Hey Dvarga, tried, but unfortunately did not work.  Cheers